# PHP Implementation for ACINQ/Strike API

Tags: php, curl, post

I need to implement the following curl using PHP.

```
$ curl https://api.dev.strike.acinq.co/api/v1/charges \ 
-u sk_pJDwxFxCVw5fQJhRRMpf29jReUjjN: \
-X POST \
-d amount=42000 \
-d currency="btc" \
-d description="1%20Blockaccino"
```

This is what I have so far.

```
$post=array();
$post["amount"]=4200;
$post["currency"]="btc";
$post["description"]="1%20Blockaccino";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "sk_pJDwxFxCVw5fQJhRRMpf29jReUjjN:");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.dev.strike.acinq.co/api/v1/charges");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$http = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
if ($http==200) { 
} else {
}
```

It returns

```
{ "code" : 401, "message" : "authentication failed" }
```

Even though the CURLOPT_USERNAME is accurate. Are there other issues I am not seeing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like your API key is not valid ? have you tried using curl and are you able to get success result?

Comment: I get the same result using native curl so I think you are correct and the message I am getting is accurate... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`CURLOPT_USERNAME` was added in PHP 5.5.0.

If you have an older version then you may want to try:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "sk_pJDwxFxCVw5fQJhRRMpf29jReUjjN:");
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, unfortunately same result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final WORKING solution...

```
$post=array();
$post["amount"]=100000;
$post["currency"]="btc";
$post["description"]="test";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "sk_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.strike.acinq.co/api/v1/charges");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($post));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Content-Type: application/json"));   
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$http = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
if ($http==200) { 
} else {
}
```